# How to make variable size string for sprintf

Tags: c++

I want to make variable size string "msg" like this.

```
char *msg;
sprintf(msg,"Msg",variable)
```

i dont want to use string .
What would be the best solution

Comment: If you don't want use `std::string`, then why not C tag also?

Comment: Why don't you want to use string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings are fixed size. `<string>` is variable size. If you don't want to use `string` but still have a variable size, you will have to tell us why you don't want to use `<string>`, or we will just tell you that it *is* the solution to your problem.

Perhaps you simply don't know your way around `<string>`, perhaps you only know `sprintf()` and realized you cannot use it to write into a `std::string`? In that case, I recommend and present to you `<sstream>` and the `operator<<()` syntax of C++ output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// Using C-style I/O here to make it easier for you.
// You *should* use <iostream> and std::cout instead.
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int variable = 42;

    // creating a string stream, and writing to it.
    std::ostringstream myStream;
    myStream << "Msg" << variable;

    // extract the string from the string stream
    std::string myString = myStream.str();

    // extract C string from C++ string
    // CAREFUL - the return value is a *temporary* as well as a *constant*.
    printf( "%s\n", myString.c_str() );

    // of course, you can extract the C string directly from the stream
    printf( "%s\n", myStream.str().c_str() );

    // as I said above, in C++ you would use std::cout instead of printf() -
    // and you would not need to extract C style strings anymore.
    std::cout << myString << " - " << myStream.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If that doesn't scratch your itch, perhaps `snprintf()` is what you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MSG_LENGTH 1000

int main()
{
    int variable = 42;
    char msg[ MSG_LENGTH ];
    if ( snprintf( msg, MSG_LENGTH, "Msg%d", variable ) > MSG_LENGTH )
    {
        // your buffer was not large enough
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The additional numeric parameter to `snprintf()` makes sure that there is no writing beyond the end of the buffer if the buffer is too short. But that's pure C, and your question should've been tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a variable size string for sprintf.  The sprintf function doesn't know or care how big the destination buffer (variable) is.  It's up to the caller to make sure the buffer is sufficiently large to receive the result.  Try this and you will see that when sprintf runs out of space in buf1 it happily continues past the end and overwrites buf2 (at least in VC9 and gcc443)...

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Bufs {
   char buf1[7];
   char buf2[7];
};

int main() {
   Bufs bufs;
   sprintf(bufs.buf1, "Hello, World!");
   printf(bufs.buf1);
}
```